# Reference Request: Source of Prime Number Theorem (without The Analytic Theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, analysis, reference-request, prime-numbers

Generally most of the proof I found online are  based on *The Analytic Theorem* , that proof was sketched  by Von Newman. In a book I found a different proof.

The proof first derived 
$\int_2^x\frac{\psi(u)}{ u^2}du= \log x+O(1)$, then it showed- 
$$\varliminf \frac {\psi(x)}{ x}\leq 1 $$
$$\varlimsup \frac {\psi(x)}{ x}\geq 1 $$

Then the author used the fact- 
$$\pi(x)\sim \frac{\theta(x)}{\log x}\sim \frac{\psi(x)}{\log x}$$
Showing-
$$\varliminf \frac {\pi(x)}{ x/\log x}\leq 1 $$
$$\varlimsup \frac {\psi(x)}{ x/\log x}\geq 1 $$
Saying that if $\frac {\pi(x)}{ x/\log x}$ tend to a limit as $x \to \infty$, then the limit must be 1, thus, 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac {\pi(x)}{ x/\log x}=1$$

what is the original source of this proof? Who gave above proof?
Plz, give the reference (book, journal paper).

Comment: Note that this doesn't prove that the limit exists, only **if** the limit exists, then it is $1$. That result is by Chebyshev.